# Oracle TYPE 2 JDBC Create Table Error

Tags: java, jdbc

Here the program is to create a table using OCI driver but it is showing the following error.

[image: Error Message]

```
import java.sql.*;
public class CreateTable{
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
Connection con;
Statement ps;
String query;
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:oci8:orcl","scott","tiger");
query="CREATE TABLE Employee (roll number(3))";
ps=con.createStatement();
ps.executeUpdate(query);
System.out.println("Table created");
ps.close();
con.close();
}
}
```

Comment: You aren't actually connecting to anything (per your error), you almost certainly need to setup your [Local Naming Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm#NETRF007) (`tnsnames.ora`). **Why** are you using a Type 2 driver? The Oracle Type 4 driver is faster... And if you still have scott / tiger - disable them!

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace as text, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
try (
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
   "jdbc:oracle:oci8:orcl","scott","tiger"); // MySQL
         Statement ps = conn.createStatement();
       {
       String query="CREATE TABLE Employee (roll number(3))";
        ps=con.createStatement();
         ps.executeUpdate(query);
          System.out.println("Table created");
         System.out.println("Table created");
         }
      } catch(SQLException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
ps.close();
con.close();
}
}
```

It's better to use Type 4 Connectivity because their Java drivers are for "direct-to-database".

Comment: Please add a description of what you changed from the original code, and why. None of the changes you introduced are related to problem.